# Which one of the following is correct in terms of grammar?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one of the following is correct in terms of grammar?

> 1. It is there for to read.
> 2. It is there for reading.
> 3. It is there to read.

Comment: It is there **to be** read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you are talking about. If you are talking about something that you can read (for example a notice, book, magazine or newspaper), 3 is the best option. **it** is an implied object of **to read**:

> it is there to read [it].

If it is something that you might use in order to read (a table that you can sit at while reading, a reading light, a microfiche reader) 2 is the best option. Reading is an activity, and **it** is something that helps you with that activity. **for** ([Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for) meaning 4) specifies the purpose of **it**.